# When did Sirius Black give Harry the mirror that he has during his stay in the Forest of Dean?

Tags: harry-potter

In ***Harry Potter And The Deathly Hallows Part 1***,
Aberforth Dumbledore watches Harry and the group through a mirror when the trio are searching for horcruxes.

In ***Harry Potter And The Deathly Hallows Part 2***,
when the trio get back to Hogwarts, they end up in Aberforth's place.
There, Harry sees a broken mirror and when he questions Aberforth, Aberforth tells him that Mundungs Fletcher had given him that mirror. Harry replies saying Mundungs had no right to give Aberforth that mirror as it belonged to Sirius.

1. So, the mirror belonged to Sirius.
2. It was stolen by Mundungs.

My question is

- Why was the mirror broken into 2 pieces?
- And how come Harry had a piece of the mirror?

Comment: http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Two-way_mirror

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shard wasn't from *that* mirror. They were *twin two-way mirrors* that were connected and allowed people to communicate through them. The shard was from *Harry's* mirror, which he broke after he tossed it in his trunk, because he felt it was useless after Sirius' death (this is explained in the book). Aberforth got hold of the *other* one (Sirius') to keep an eye on Harry.

**EDIT:** I'm struggling to remember if the mirrors appeared in the films prior to **The Deathly Hallows**. It's very possible that they were omitted from them and the viewers had to rely on their knowledge of the books.

Comment: In the movie, there is only one mirror, Aberforth has the broken mirror, and Harry is holding the missing piece.  The movie fails to make any sense of it.

Answer (score 3):

Harry does have a shard of mirror that he looks into throughout, particularly, *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part II* **Walt** gives an explanation, above, but he is giving the story from the books, which do not occur identically in the movies. Viewers will remember that the twin to Harry's shard of mirror is with Aberforth Dumbledore, Professor Dumbledore's brother. The mirrors do not appear before the two *Deathly Hallows* movies.

In the movies, if I'm recalling correctly, the Sirius backstory is not given. That frees up the writers to toss out the Mundungus plot line. Neither movie explains why the mirror is broken into two pieces -- it's really extraneous information and really doesn't matter (Aside from the inconvenience of carrying around a pocketful of glass shards). I don't believe it's explained why Harry has this piece of mirror. He just ... does!

Comment: You're right, and I completely forgot that the movie just didn't explain it (which is... not a great solution). I tried deleting my answer, but it won't let me.